# Mule throw exception in a catch exception block

Tags: exception, mule

I have the following mule flow:

1. Do something
2. Throws exception
3. caught by *Catch* exception block
4. in the catch block, try something else
5. throws exception
6. exception is **squashed** coming out of the catch block

How can i get the exception thrown inside the catch block to surface outside the catch block?

Comment: Could you provide more information, like mule version, xml config, stack trace?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

An exception strategy can't handle an exception that happened inside. 
What you can do is to use a `flow-ref` to use a different flow with a different exception strategy for your second try.

Comment: I assume I can't call the flow-ref from inside the catch block. Will have to set a flowVar that get's picked up when the flow continues.